# Add border to images 1 bpp indexed

Tags: c#, image

I want to add a border to an Image.

To achieve that, I want to crate a new empty image with size equal to old size + border size, copy old image on center and draw border :

[image]

There is the method I wrote :

```
private Bitmap addBorderToImage(Image image, int borderSize)
{
    Bitmap bmpTmp = new Bitmap(image);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpTmp.Width + 2 * borderSize,
                            bmpTmp.Height + 2 * borderSize,
                            bmpTmp.PixelFormat);

    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
    BitmapData dataTmp = bmpTmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpTmp.Width, bmpTmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
    // Copy the bytes from the image into a byte array
    for (int y = 0; y < bmpTmp.Height; y++)
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(dataTmp.Scan0, y * data.Stride, (IntPtr)((long)data.Scan0 + data.Stride * y + borderSize), y * data.Stride);
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    bmpTmp.UnlockBits(data);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Green, borderSize * 2), new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

But I'm unable to do a correct copy. I have error :

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'byte[]'

How should I do the `Marshal.Copy` ?

**Edit:** I use Marshall.copy instead of graphics cause I can't create graphics element from Format1bppIndexed.

Comment: Why are you using `Marshal.Copy` instead of simply drawing the image?.

Comment: I did some research, but my problem is my format. With images Format1bppIndexed, I can't do the drawImage.

Comment: The comment says "Copy the bytes from the image into a byte array", but you never define or initialize any byte array. That's the argument it's complaining about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `Marshal.Copy` is expecting a `byte []` array that's why it doesn't compile.

Second, you don't need to have low byte manipulation  as `Graphics` handles all operation you need for this job (this is an *authentic* [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Last, there are many undisposed object in your original code which will leads you to memory leaks.

What about the following :

```
    private static Bitmap AddBorderToImage(Image image, int borderSize)
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image.Width + 2 * borderSize,
            image.Height + 2 * borderSize))
        {
            using (Graphics destGraph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                destGraph.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bmp.Size));
                destGraph.DrawImage(image, new Point(borderSize, borderSize));
            }

            return bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), image.PixelFormat);
        }
    }
```

The idea is as simple as this:

- Create a new result bitmap with the background of border's color
- Draw the inner original image at the correct place (*borderSize*, *borderSize*).
- Clone the final result with original PixelFormat

Comment: I've try this but I have an error `A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.` My Image format is Format1bppIndexed

Comment: @A.Pissicat : Just remove the third argument like in my edit

Comment: It works good with your edit but the new image is format `Format32bppArgb`. My images are in grey scale and I want them the smallest possible. Is there a way to conserve format `Format1bppIndexed ` ?

Comment: For this you can just call `return bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)` before returning. In this case , don't forget to surrond bmp with ùsing`. I made an edit

Comment: You will have to work with the images in something other than 1bppIndexed, and then convert them back before saving or whatnot, 1bpp isn't well supported by GDI+ or .NET (I forget which one isn't really supporting it).

Comment: Converting it back works, unless the 1bpp image's colours happen to _not_ be black and white (which is perfectly possible); then you have to be careful to adjust things correctly. Simplest way is to save the colours in advance, change the palette to b/w, then process it, and then restore the original colours after making the new 1bpp clone.

Answer (score 0):

I used System.Drawing and got the results. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
private Bitmap AddBorder(Image original_image, int border_size, Color border_color)
    {
        Size originalSize = new Size(original_image.Width + border_size, original_image.Height + border_size);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(originalSize.Width, originalSize.Height);
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), originalSize);
        Pen pen = new Pen(border_color, border_size);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
        rec.Inflate(-border_size /2, -border_size /2);
        g.DrawImage(original_image, rec);
        return bmp;
    }
```